# Countable union of a countable many collection is the power set of that collection

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

i'm trying to prove that cannot exists a countable sigma algebra (not trivial).

So, the statement is the following:

Let $X$ a set and let $\mathcal{M}$ a sigma algebra on X. Show that $\mathcal{M}$ is finite or is uncountable.

*Proof*.  If $X$ is finite, the thesis is obviuos because the power set of $X$ is finite. So, let $X$ a infinite set and suppose that $\mathcal{M}$ is infinite countable.

So, exists $\mathcal{M}'\subseteq \mathcal{M}$ countable subfamily. Because $\mathcal{M}$ is a sigma algebra, then it must contains every countable union of the elements contained in $\mathcal{M}'$. The set of all these unions is the power set of $\mathcal{M}'$. Moreover, the power set of $\mathcal{M}'$ is uncountable (known fact).

In the end, we have that $\mathcal{M}$ contains a uncontable subfamily, which is an absurd assuming that $\mathcal{M}$ is countable.

Is my argument correct? If it is, how can I prove the fact that the set of all unions is the power set of $\mathcal{M}'$?

thanks.

Comment: The only set $X$ I am aware of such that "The set of the countable unions of elements contained in $X$ is the power set of $X$" is true is $X=\emptyset$. Did you have another one in mind?

Comment: What if $\mathcal{M}'=\{\{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,1,2\},\{0,1,2,3\},\ldots\}$.  The union of every infinite countable subset of $\mathcal{M}'$ is $\Bbb{N}$.  The union of every finite subset of $\mathcal{M}'$ is $\{0,\ldots,m\}$ for some $m$.  So you get only countably many sets this way.

Comment: @ChadK Any sigma algebra containing your set also contains every singleton $\{n\} =\{0, …, n\} \setminus \{0, …, n-1\}$.

Comment: @BrianO: I was referring to the post, but thanks for paying attention.  Now bother reading it.

Comment: @ChadK i tried reading it; it doesn’t make a ton of sense. Neither does your reply.

Comment: @BrianO: OP is trying to prove that an infinite $\sigma$-algebra is uncountable by claiming that if you start with a family of countably-many sets, by taking all possible unions of a sub-family - you get uncoutnably many sets.  I showed why this is false.

Comment: @ChadK A noble deed, and helpful. I was dismayed at OP’s apparent assumption that Sigma algebra’s are  closed under only countable union. As you showed, that is not necessarily enough to turn a countable collection into an uncountable one.